# R: How to append a list to a list, and then assign each list to a row in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am attaching the lists to a list in the following way:

```
list1= list(4,5,6)
list2= list(1,2,3)
list3= c(list1, list2)
```

Then I want to attach these list of list in the following way in my dataframe:

```
list_colA = c(x,z)

A   B
x  [4,5,6]
z  [1,2,3]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You example doesn't produce a list of lists -- `list3` is just a list of length 6. Did you mean `list3 = list(list1, list2)`? Does your desired output have just two columns? You want to store lists in your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
list_colA = c('x','z')
df <- data.frame(A = list_colA)
df$B <- list(list1, list2)
df

#  A       B
#1 x 4, 5, 6
#2 z 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(A = c('x', 'z'), B = lst(list1, list2))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A     B           
#  <chr> <named list>
#1 x     <list [3]>  
#2 z     <list [3]>
```